# Discord.js message is not defined. Message Embed

Tags: discord.js

I have recently started moving all my commands into files to clear it up a bit. The code in index.js is fine. I keep getting RefrenceError: message id not defined. This is the code. Thanks in advance

```
module.exports = {
 name: 'help',
 description: "this is help command",
 execute(mesage, args){
         if (args[1] === 'staff'){
             const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
             .setTitle ("Staff Commands:")
             .addField ("**g!mute <user> <time>**", "Will mute the user for the specified amount of time. **PLEASE REPORT WHY YOU MUTED PERSON IN** #mute-people")
             .setColor(0xfc8e08)
             message.channel.send(embed);
         }else
         if (args[1] === 'krunker'){
             const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
             .setTitle ("Krunker::")
             .addField ("**g!profile**", "Will give you a link to my Krunker.io profile")
             .addField ("**g!trade**", "Will Display the t&c for trading")
             .addField ("**g!clan**", "will give the link to my Clan [G3O]")
             .addField ("**g!scope**", "will give the scope I made/use")
             .addField ("**g!overlay**", "will give overlay I made/use")
             .addField ("**g!hitmarker**", "will give the hitmarker I made/use")
             .addField ("**g!mod**", "will give the mod I made")
             .addField ("**g!settings**", "will give the settings I use")
             .setColor(0xfce808)
             message.channel.send(embed);
         }else
         if (args[1] === 'socials'){
             const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
             .setTitle ("Socials:")
             .addField ("**g!twitch**", "Will give you a link to my Twitch")
             .addField ("**g!yt**", "Will give the link to my Youtube Channel")
             .addField ("**g!twitter**", "will give the link to my Twitter")
             .addField ("**g!instagram**", "will give the link to my Instagram")
             .addField ("**g!tiktok**", "will give the link to my TikTok")
             .addField ("**g!socials**", "will give the link where you can find all of my socials")
             .setColor(0xfc0808)
             message.channel.send(embed);
         }else{
             const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
             .setTitle ("Commands List:")
             .addField ("**g!help socials**", "Will give you a list of commands for my socials")
             .addField ("**g!help staff**", "Will give a list of commands for STAFF ONLY")
             .addField ("**g!help krunker**", "Will give a list of commands all realted to Krunker")
             .setColor(0x01B8FF)
             message.channel.send(embed)
     }
 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving the error because you misspelled `message` at your `execute` function.

You spelled `mesage` instead of `message`.

```js
module.exports = {
 name: 'help',
 description: "this is help command",
 execute(message, args){
         if (args[1] === 'staff'){
             const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
             .setTitle ("Staff Commands:")
             .addField ("**g!mute <user> <time>**", "Will mute the user for the specified amount of time. **PLEASE REPORT WHY YOU MUTED PERSON IN** #mute-people")
             .setColor(0xfc8e08)
             message.channel.send(embed);
         }else
         if (args[1] === 'krunker'){
             const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
             .setTitle ("Krunker::")
             .addField ("**g!profile**", "Will give you a link to my Krunker.io profile")
             .addField ("**g!trade**", "Will Display the t&c for trading")
             .addField ("**g!clan**", "will give the link to my Clan [G3O]")
             .addField ("**g!scope**", "will give the scope I made/use")
             .addField ("**g!overlay**", "will give overlay I made/use")
             .addField ("**g!hitmarker**", "will give the hitmarker I made/use")
             .addField ("**g!mod**", "will give the mod I made")
             .addField ("**g!settings**", "will give the settings I use")
             .setColor(0xfce808)
             message.channel.send(embed);
         }else
         if (args[1] === 'socials'){
             const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
             .setTitle ("Socials:")
             .addField ("**g!twitch**", "Will give you a link to my Twitch")
             .addField ("**g!yt**", "Will give the link to my Youtube Channel")
             .addField ("**g!twitter**", "will give the link to my Twitter")
             .addField ("**g!instagram**", "will give the link to my Instagram")
             .addField ("**g!tiktok**", "will give the link to my TikTok")
             .addField ("**g!socials**", "will give the link where you can find all of my socials")
             .setColor(0xfc0808)
             message.channel.send(embed);
         }else{
             const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
             .setTitle ("Commands List:")
             .addField ("**g!help socials**", "Will give you a list of commands for my socials")
             .addField ("**g!help staff**", "Will give a list of commands for STAFF ONLY")
             .addField ("**g!help krunker**", "Will give a list of commands all realted to Krunker")
             .setColor(0x01B8FF)
             message.channel.send(embed)
     }
 
 }
}
```